# Math riddle puzzle

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle

I stumbled upon this math puzzle over one android app.

You need to find the unknown number in the puzzle.

```
92 = 725
61 = 215
74 = 327
52 = ?
```

According to the author of the app, the right answer is **121**. But I cannot find why. What is the logic for this answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, really:

> ab = a^3 - b^2

Comment: Would you like to elaborate more? I do not get it?

Comment: for example: 52 -> $5^3$ - $2^2$ = 125 - 4 = 121.